# Error in fetch data while using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For fetching userid from database when a user login using PDO, my $stmt is not executing and I am neitjer getting userid. Can you find error in this code please?

```
function signin_user($email, $password) {
    //prepare email address and password hash for safe query
    $email   = $email;
    $pwdhash = hash("SHA1", $password);

    //connect to MySQL
    try {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=company';

        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');
        echo "connected to database";

        $userid = 0;
        $stmt   = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM company_description(email,password) WHERE VALUES (:email,:password)");
        $stmt->bindvalue(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindvalue(':password', $pwdhash);
        $stmt->execute()
        foreach ($stmt as $id) {
                $userid=$id['id'];
        }
        echo $userid;

        // close the database connection
        $dbh = null;
        return $userid;
    }
     catch (PDOException $e) {
        //try/catch are like if/else in PDO
        //PDOexception/$e/getMessage() arefunction in PDO's API and they don't die unlike mysql_connect fashion
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

**__UPDATE__**
Thanks to all of you for taking time and address my problem. It has solved now and the right/working code looks like as

```
//connect to MySQL
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=company';

        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');

        //PDO error throwing expression, so PDO doesn't die without telling reason
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        //escaping strings and selecting data from database
        $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id FROM company_descriptioin WHERE email=? AND password = ?');
        $sth->execute(array($email, $pwdhash));

        $userid = 0;
        //fetching the data in a assosiative array
        $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $userid = $result['id'];

        // close database and return null
        $dbh = null;
        return $userid;
```

Comment: Could you post the error messages you're getting? If any.

Comment: Ashvini, do you still need help? I was waiting for your feedback

Comment: Thanks meda, but i have figured out the problem :)

Comment: Opps! my reputation points are only 1, I can't upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to insert into the table

**For that you need to change your query**

```
    $stmt   = $dbh->prepare("Insert into company_description(email,password) VALUES 
(':email',':password')");
```

And If I am wrong and you really want to fetch the data then you should do this

```
$stmt   = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,email,password FROM company_description");
        $stmt->query();
```

**Note:-**

`execute()` is used in case of inserting or updating the values while `query()` is used for fetching the data

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can write like below: AS per [Php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id
    FROM company_description
    WHERE email = :email AND password = :password');
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':password' => $pwdhash));
```

Answer (score 0):

Think there is issue with your SQL syntax:

```
$stmt   = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM company_description(email,password) WHERE VALUES (:email,:password)");
```

To:

```
$stmt   = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM company_description WHERE (email=:email AND password=:password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query has invalid syntax, and you never fetched the data after `execute()`

try this:

```
function signin_user($email, $password) {
    //connect to MySQL
    try {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=company';

        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');
        echo "connected to database";

        $query = "
                  SELECT id 
                  FROM company_description 
                  WHERE email = :email AND password = :password
                 ";

        $stmt   = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindvalue(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindvalue(':password', hash("SHA1", $password));
        $stmt->execute()

        if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            return $row['id'];
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
     catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }

}
```

usage:

```
$user_id = singin_user("some@email.com", "somepass");
if($user_id != false){
   echo 'user_id = '.$user_id;
}
```